# Parse.com query objects where the key's array value contains any of the elements

Tags: parse-platform

on https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#queries-arrays there is an example how to find objects where the key's array value contains each of the elements 2, 3, and 4 with the following:

```
// Find objects where the array in arrayKey contains all of the elements 2, 3, and 4.
query.containsAll("arrayKey", [2, 3, 4]);
```

However, I would like to find objects where the key's array value contains **at least one (not necessarily all)** of the elements 2,3, and 4.

Is that possible?

Comment: Can you make containsAll work? Mine is not working.

Comment: See selected answer: query.containedIn("arrayKey", [2,3,4]);      Note that Parse.com is hutting down...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm not positive, but what happens if you try `containedIn`?

I think if you pass an array, it checks to see if any are contained.

```
query.containedIn("arrayKey", [2,3,4]);
```

I know that if you use `equalTo` with an array key and a singular value, it checks if the value is in the array and returns TRUE.  I think this will do something similar and should work.  I think it will check if any value in "arrayKey" is in the passed array.  If any key object does, it will return the object.

Comment: can we have two containedIn, for two separate keys, in one query?
query.containedIn("Key1", [2,3,4]);
query.containedIn("Key2", [7,8,9]);

Comment: Yes, if it's an AND query so both would be required to be true. If it's an OR query, you'd have to use sub queries if one or the either can be true.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. It's an AND query but why is it that when I add both, I get no objects returned. remove the second one and it works

Comment: Are you sure that some objects satisfy your query?

Comment: Ahh I was too focused on searching for an error rather than looking at my own. My second containedIn had all the strings.uppercase so it was not matching with what was in the database. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

## swift 3.0

```
let Query:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: “className”)
Query.whereKey(“Field Name”, containedIn: array)// [“1”,”2”,”3”];
```